# Twilio new API 5.x

Tags: c#, twilio

I just want to validate if someone is being testing the new Twilio helper classes 5.x for C# and how Exception management is being managed now.  The new API broke my code because of the following:

I have in my code a Send Message method like this one:

```
public static MessageResource SendMessage(SmsMessage smsMessage, out MessageResource msgResult)
{
    _log.DebugFormat( "[ClassName: {0}] [Executing Method: {1}]", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name );

    SmsConfiguration smsRestClient = new  SmsConfiguration( smsMessage.ChannelName );

    msgResult = MessageResource.Create(
                  from: new PhoneNumber(smsMessage.MessageFrom),
                    to: new PhoneNumber(smsMessage.MessageTo),
                  body: smsMessage.MessageBody,
              mediaUrl: new List<Uri>() { new Uri( smsMessage.MessageAttachments ) },
        statusCallback: new Uri( smsRestClient.ConfigToSmsStatusCallbackUrl.isValidUrl( false ) ? smsRestClient.ConfigToSmsStatusCallbackUrl : null)
    );

    return msgResult;
}
```

The new static method Init is being performed within `SmsConfiguration`, no problems there.  But in my 4.x version instead of `MessageResource` I've been using the Message class and that Message class had a `RestException` which contained all the error from Twilio, now if I used `MessageResource` I need to use a `Try..Catch` and `msgResult` never got populated.  Because of that every single code line form that point on explode because that `msgResult` variable is only been populated with successful messages passed to Twilio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a solution! Must implement the [`ApiException`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-csharp/5.0.0/class_twilio_1_1_exceptions_1_1_api_exception.html) instead of the SystemException.  With the APIException I created an Object of type `MessageResult` with the Exception and the `MessageResource` as properties, then fill accordingly with a `boolean` flag for `RestException` simulation.